Bazel windows binary .exe file doesn't install anything, but instead opens "Bazel is a command line tool..." text in cmd window
I'm trying to install an older version of Bazel (0.17.2) and therefore cannot use Chocolatey or Bazelisk (as those automatically install the latest version). I'm instead trying to install it through the windows binary .exe file found in the Github's "Releases" section (titled "bazel-0.17.2-windows-x86_64.exe").
However, when I downloaded the .exe file and ran it, instead of installing the correct Bazel version, it opens this dialogue in Command Prompt:
Bazel is a command line tool.

Try opening a console, such as the Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe) or PowerShell, and running "bazel help".

Press Enter to close this window...

I can't enter any commands into the window because when I press Enter, it instantly closes the window. Is there some other way to download a specific version of Bazel? I also can't find any .py or .exe file in the "Source code" zip file in the Github's "Releases" section that I can run to activate or download Bazel (usually there's a "setup.exe" file, but here there's not). What can I do? Thanks!

Type *command" into the Windows search box on the taskbar. Choose command prompt from the list of suggestions. It opens the command prompt that the message is mentioning. Run the executable from there by typing its name, and see what happens. Command line tools need to be run from a command prompt, not by double-clicking them.

The .exe files for Windows aren't installers, it's the bazel.exe binary itself. Just run the file you downloaded (either directly as it is in your downloads folder, or copy/move it somewhere else first to "install" it).
Also, Bazelisk does support using older versions. The easiest way is creating a file named .bazelversion with 0.17.2 as its contents (at the root of your workspace, next to the WORKSPACE file). See the docs for details and other configuration options.
